# get a specific number between others numbers with regex_substr in oracle SQL/PLSQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

i've this string '0136541274114225**99**412405412123AB>Z4204015479'. i need all digits between `99` (it may be 10)  and `>`.

I tried get this with:

```
 regexp_substr('013654127411422599412405412123AB>Z4204015479','[^99|10](.)([^(>)]+)')
```

but it doesn´t work. the result was:

```
3654127411422599412405412123AB
```

expected result:

412405412123AB

Someone could help me, please?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and provide another examples of the desired results?

Comment: What's the result if `<` comes _before_ `99`? Or if there's a `<` but no `99`, or `99` but no `<`, or several of them?

Comment: What to do if `99` and/or `>` appear multiple times within the string, what to do if only one of them or none appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT regexp_substr(
  '013654127411422599412405412123AB>Z4204015479',
  '(99|10)(\w+)>', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS Result;
```

Also, if there can be more than word chars, just use

```
'(99|10)([^>]+)'
```

The `(99|10)(\w+)>` regex matches and capture into Group 1 either `99` or `10`, then captures into Group 2 any one or more word characters, followed with a `>` char.

The `(99|10)([^>]+)` regex is a bit more generic, it matches and captures into Group 2 `99` or `10` and then captures into Group 2 any one or more chars other than `>`.

Note the `2` argument in `regexp_substr`, it extracts the value stored in Group 2.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be regex? Because, on large data sets `substr + instr` combination will most probably outperform it and is rather *trivial*.

Sample data (underlined part represents desired result):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select  '013654127411422599412405412123AB>Z4204015479' from dual)
  3    --                          --------------
```

Query:

```
  4  select substr(col, instr(col, '99') + 2,
  5                     instr(col, '>') - instr(col, '99') - 2
  6               ) result
  7  from test;

RESULT
--------------
412405412123AB

SQL>
```